# Opengl Compile on Ubuntu using Makefile

Tags: ubuntu, opengl, makefile, compilation

I'm using an open source named "libjpeg-turbo" on Ubuntu.
I want to add some OpenGL codes into libjpeg-turbo.
As you know, OpenGL needs to add some libraries which are "-lGL -lGLU -lglut -lm" when compiling on Ubuntu. 
However, "libjpeg-turbo" compiles all source codes using Makefile. 
I have no idea how to modify Makefile to compile OpenGL on Ubuntu.

Please, help me to fix it. 
Thanks,

Comment: What do You mean by saying _complie OpenGL_? Do You want to rewrite some of the code of libjpeg-turbo using OpenGL?

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean that. I want to add some OpenGL code into a source code of libjpeg-turbo.

Comment: I think you'll have to learn about `makefiles` first, then ask questions about things you did not understand, and after that you'll have an idea how to modify your `makefile` to achieve the thing you need.